# checking object reference equality using == (in Java)

Tags: java

Why does...

```
    String a = new String("a");
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("a");
    System.out.println(a==b);
```

... result in an incompatible types error when compiling given that...

```
    String a = new String("b");
    Object b = new StringBuilder("b");
    System.out.println(a==b);
```

... does not?

Why can I compare the object references of a String and an Object but not a StringBuilder and a String? Aren't they all just addresses to memory locations?

Thanks

Comment: String is `Object` not `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Would it ever be possible to `String` and `StringBuilder` references hold same instance? If no then what is the point of `a==b` test? Now would it be possible for `Object` and `StringBuilder` references to hold same instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acording to the Java Language Specification (15.21.3):

> It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion (§5.5). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be unequal (ignoring the case where both values are null).

Which means, in order to "compare" two reference types, one should be able to be cast to the other. String "is" an object, but there is no "cast" between `String` and `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I'll refer to the specification first in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The compiler tries to help you.

When the `==` can never be true because of conflicting types, it assumes you made a mistake and will refuse to compile the code.

Happens with `instanceof` as well, and also with casts.

```
String a = null;
if (a instanceof StringBuilder){} // compile-error
StringBuilder b = (StringBuilder) a;  // compile-error
```

Answer (score 3):

Because, `String` is an `Object` but `String` is not `StringBuilder`. You can compare reference using `==` on same type and supertype. Look at following example

```
class A{

}
class B extends A{

}

class C{

}
```

Now,

```
  A a =new A();
  A b =new B(); // or B b =new B();
  C c= new C();

  System.out.println(a==b); // It is ok
  System.out.println(a==c); // It will generate compile time error
```

Comment: or B b =new B(); as the question asker just demonstrated this comment is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

String extends the `Object` type, like any other class, but does not inherit `StringBuilder`. Hence in your comparison `String` falls back to `Object` and they *have* a type in common.

Answer (score 1):

Because both Strings and StringBuilders are children of the `Object` class. They are however not the same class, so they cannot be compared using `==`. You would need to call the `toString` method on `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

In second example String is also an Object since all classes subclass Object and you can check if they are ==.

In first example you compare String to StringBuilder which are different classes and neither is subclass of the other so the operator fails.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to compare *compatible types*, since comparing incompatible types for equality will always be `false`.

`String` is compatible with `Object`, so comparing references with those types is not a compile-time error. `StringBuilder` is compatible with `Object`, so you can assign a `StringBuilder` to an `Object`-typed variable. But `String` and `StringBuilder` are not compatible with *each other*. So if you have a `String` reference, and an `Object` reference, you can compare them without a compile-time error. But if you have a `String` reference and a `StringBuilder` reference, you can't — the compiler knows that the comparison will never be `true`.

Note how it's all about the type of the references (the variables), not the type of the objects assigned to them. That's why it's possible to set up your second scenario and have it compile, even though it can never have a true result.